# Codeigniter SELECT from TABLE problems

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have this code, in my Model:

```
public function get_all_distinct() {
        $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(tag) FROM `tags_to_questions`';
        $result = array(
            'assignedTags' => array(),
            'availableTags2' => $this->db->query($query)->result_array(),

        );
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

And this code will return me an array (json type) like:

```
{"assignedTags":[],"availableTags2":[{"tag":"php"},{"tag":"mysql"}]}
```

What to change in my code to get an array like:

```
{"assignedTags":[],"availableTags2":[{"php"},{"mysql"}]}
```

I just need the values from the  key, not with the key.

Comment: add 2nd parameter in your json to TRUE

Comment: json_encode doesn't accept true as second param. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need a foreach to do so. There is no automatic way.

```
$tmp = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
foreach($tmp as $cell=> $row) {
    $tmp_result[] = $row;
}

$result = array(
    'assignedTags' => array(),
    'availableTags2' => $tmp_result,
);
return json_encode($result);
```

Comment: It will return the same result as mine. I figured out how to make it. Thank you.

$query2 = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($query2->result() as $row)
        {
            $availableTags[] = $row->tag;
        }

Comment: Yes you are probably right because the names on the variables where wrong. I made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a feasible or not but you can use `array_column` as

```
public function get_all_distinct() {
        $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(tag) FROM `tags_to_questions`';
        $result = array(
            'assignedTags' => array(),
            'availableTags2' => $this->db->query($query)->result_array(),

        );
        $result['availableTags2'] = array_column($result['availableTags2'],'tag');
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: So where are we with question. Did it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_values()](https://www.php.net/array_values). This will do:

```
public function get_all_distinct() {
        $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(tag) FROM `tags_to_questions`';
        $result = array(
            'assignedTags' => array(),
            'availableTags2' => array_values($this->db->query($query)->result_array()),

        );
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```